# left join with OR clause

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables, shown simplified below:

```
Table 1: | id | somedata | checkcode
Table 2: | id | somedata | checkcode1 | checkcode2
```

I would need to left join the second one where checkcode1 OR checkcode2 is like checkcode. I tried to make two distinct left join, but that did not work, since it included double the data.

What I would need is something like this:

```
Select * from Table1 as t1     
LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 
on t1.checkcode = (t2.checkcode1 OR t2.checkcode2)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try to simply write the condition explicitly?

`Select * from Table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 on (t1.checkcode = t2.checkcode1 OR t1.checkcode = t2.checkcode2)`

Comment: yay this worked! if you post it as answre i accept your since you were the first. thanks!

Comment: Here's a clue: IN()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
Select * from Table1 as t1  
LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.checkcode = t2.checkcode1 OR t1.checkcode = t2.checkcode2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this as you are saying "I would need to left join the second one where checkcode1 OR checkcode2 is **like** checkcode"

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON CONCAT(Table2.checkcode1,Table2.checkcode2) LIKE CONCAT('%', Table1.checkcode, '%')
```

**EDIT**

```
select * from Table1 as t1  
LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.checkcode IN(t2.checkcode1 ,t2.checkcode2)
```

Comment: you are right, the like word is my mistake. i need it to be exact. sorry. the solution by sahar bental worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.checkcode LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.checkcode1, '%') 
OR t1.checkcode LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.checkcode2, '%'));
```

You can replace `LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.checkcode2, '%')` with `= t2.checkcode2` if you want to perform the exact string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this way to perform your `LEFT JOIN`.

```
Select * from Table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.checkcode IN (t2.checkcode1,t2.checkcode2);
```

check this on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05cd0c/3)